# Different numpy dtype between Windows and Mac

Tags: windows, macos, numpy, dtype

When I run the code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(10)
print(a)
print(a.dtype)
```

In Windows 11 with Anaconda3 (64-bit), I get

```
10
int32
```

But when the same code is run on MacOS, also with Anaconda3 (64-bit), it results

```
10
int64
```

Why is there this difference?

Thanks.

Mateus

Comment: What kinda processors do you have?